# findIndex() method issue with internet explorer

Tags: javascript, perl, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I am doing some tests with differents browsers using the [`Selenium::Remote::Driver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver) module.

I would like to check if I find some item in my web site list, list from a framework JavaScript (which  creates grids). For this case I have to use JavaScript snippet allowed by `Selenium::Remote::Driver`.

I wrote the following code

```
$script = q{

      var paramProgramName = arguments[0];

      var list  = $('#c-list').dxList('instance');
      var items = list.option('items');
      var index = items.findIndex(function(el){ return el.name == paramProgramName; });

      list.selectItem(index);

      return ;
};

$driver->execute_script($script, $programName);
```

It works fine with Chrome and Firefox but not with Internet Explorer because the `findIndex` method is only supported by version 12 and following. For some reason I have to use version 11.

What can I do differently to get an index from every browser?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> So my question is how can i do differently to get my index for every browser ?

You have at least three options:

1. Shim `Array#findIndex`; [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) has a shim/polyfill you can use.
2. Use something else that IE11 has, such as [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (which even IE9 has):

   ```
   var index = -1;
   items.some(function(el, i) {
       if (el.name == paramProgramName) {
           index = i;
           return true;
       }
   });
   ```
3. Use something else that even IE8 has, such as `for`:

   ```
   var index = -1;
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
       if (items[i].name == paramProgramName) {
           index = i;
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

you can use http://underscorejs.org/,

how to use:

```
var index = _.findIndex(objects, function(item){
return item.name == programName;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

A better way:

```
var findArrayIndex = function (array, predicateFunction) {
    var length = array == null ? 0 : array.length;
    if (!length) {
        return -1;
    }
    var index = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        if(predicateFunction(array[i])) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Usage:

```
findArrayIndex(cachedAnnouncementsArray, function(o){return o.ID == 17;});
```

Comment: Why is this a "better" function than the one approved as the right answer? Could you please explain? I see it as over-engineered and complicated with the `predicateFunction`.

Comment: i was looking for a lodash 's _.findIndex replacement. Worked for me..

Comment: @DimitrisDamilos and upvoters of his comment - this is actually a decent and useful function - this is basically a simplified rewrite/polyfill of [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) supported in modern browsers - look at that reference and you'll see the use is the exact same as here. Instead of calling the 2nd parameter `predicateFunction`, however, it should really just be called `callback` to be consistent with other JavaScript built-in functions.

Answer (score -2):

Another way:

```
var objects = [
  { 'key' : 1, 'name' : 'ABC' },
  { 'key' : 2, 'name' : 'QLP' },
  { 'key' : 3, 'name' : 'XYZ' },
];

function filterByKey(obj) {
  if ('key' in obj) {
    return obj.key === 'some_value';
  }
}

var index = objects.indexOf(
  objects.filter(filterByKey)[0]
);
```