# Why doesn't Internet explorer 11 object support property or method 'findIndex'

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects from which I need to find a particular index and then delete the corresponding object from the array.

I used the `findIndex()` method :

```
var index = data.findIndex(x => x.OBJECTID == objectID);
data.splice(index, 1);
```

This works fine in Chrome but in IE 11, it throws

> object doesn't support property or method 'findIndex'

I solved this by using the solution from this stackoverflow answer:   [findIndex() method issue with internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698996/findindex-method-issue-with-internet-explorer)

On inspecting the console log, I noticed a difference between the array of objects in Chrome and IE 11:

In IE 11, the console log, the array of objects is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyanA.jpg)

while in Chrome, it's:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k75cx.jpg)

Notice that the objects in Chrome are of type object but in IE, they're of type [object object]. Is that why the findIndex() method fails? If so, why is the type different and if not, why does the findIndex() fail in IE 11?

Comment: *"Why"*? because it is a relatively new ES6 feature. Legacy browsers can't all be expected to retroactively add new features. This has been the way browser evolution has been for many years

Comment: [IE simply doesn't support that yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

Comment: Hmm. Is there a particular reason for the object type being [object Object] ? That part confused me.

Comment: I suspect that's just IE and Chrome differing in how to display your array in the console. I don't think it's significant. The bottom line is that IE does not support `Array.findIndex()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is not only findIndex, but also I.E. doesn't support lambda functions.

Using a for loop is inevitable for IE support. Or you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/) version of findIndex

```
var users = [
    { 'user': 'barney',  'active': false },
    { 'user': 'fred',    'active': false },
    { 'user': 'pebbles', 'active': true }
 ];

_.findIndex(users, function(o) { return o.user == 'barney'; });
```

Comment: Hi @Volem , tried using lodash but i still get that issue

Comment: array.findIndex(data => data.id == id); @Volem

Comment: Arrow functions are not supported by IE

Comment: But im using type script and i always get a tslint error to use arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

If you use compilation for your project, you might consider to install polyfill package

```
npm i --save core-js
```

or

```
yarn add core-js
```

Then to add at the top of your entry point of your project

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support